# How can I know if a channel exists or not?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I know there is a way to get list of all channels via this

```
 ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels");
```

How do I find out if a specific channel exists or not ?

**thanks in advance**

Comment: By exists, you probably mean that there is at least one installation subscribed to the channel? This might help https://www.parse.com/questions/count-a-number-of-subscribers-on-a-specific-channel

Comment: can you write answer here please ?

Comment: I cant use that solution with android , what is the var ?

Comment: **ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels")**  just get user own channel but I need all channels

Comment: you cannot, because there is no list of channels.   channels is just an array of strings on each object.  to assemble a full list you'd have to go through each installation.

Comment: Parse does not support retrieve list of all available channels. And also I want to ask why do you need such an operation?

Comment: @kingspeech actually In my case every user has channel which their username, SO I want to know that is there is a user exists or not for example **'AAA'** but I cant find username list so I want to channels